# Control characters display format in hyperterminal

Tags: c#, serial-port, hyperterminal

I am working with a serial device. On data receive, i am getting heart symbol along with actual data.
Then i decoded the ASCII value and found that it is equivalent to `<ETX>` (End of  text)
Why it is showing heart symbol for ETX??
What would be the display character for STX?? Is there any list available other control characters??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Interpretation_of_code_points_1.E2.80.9331_and_127

*Why does SO think the above link is 0 characters long?*

Comment: Aren't one-line answers and/or answers that are merely a link frowned upon?